# What kind of iPhone / iPod Touch do I need to test my app?

Tags: iphone, marketplace

I've written a fairly basic app for the iPhone, which I would like to test on at least one device and then get it onto the market place.

I don't need a data plan, so I'm considering buying an iPod touch, but I understand it doesn't have a camera, video, compass. While I don't need those for my current app, I might for a future one, nothing for sure there.

My concern about purchasing an iPhone, used or new, is that I believe I won't be able to use it without a sim card unless I jailbreak it. I'd prefer not to get involved with jailbreaking,  as I'm unclear how it would my efforts to test the app on the device and/or get the app onto the app store.

If I get a new iPhone, I would have to cancel the contract immediately, and my same concern about the lack of a sim card would apply.

I'd be interested in people's experience with this issue, e.g. starting out with iPhone apps and not having an iPhone, is with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest iPod Touch does have a camera: http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/

You should be able to test nearly everything you'd need to test on an iPod Touch.

Also, if you want to support older devices, it might be a good idea to also pick up a used, older, iPod Touch on eBay or somewhere, so you can test on a non-Retina display.

Comment: I decided to go with the touch because 1) I have an old ipod which I could trade in for a 10% discount 2) I don't need a phone 3) It's lighter than the phone 4) I don't have to worry about a sim card (although I think it would be ok) and 5) I can get started on it right away

Answer (score 1):

I have development going on without an iPhone but is preferred to develop with a device cause you could test your codes once in awhile. iPod Touch 4 does have camera. Anyway i think iPhone would still be able to function properly without a sim card just that you can't call. Otherwise getting an iPad is not that bad, since you can run both iPad and iPhone apps in iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to get the oldest slowest model of device running the oldest version of iOS on which you want you apps to be compatible.  This may also be a low cost way to get into testing on devices.  If your apps are commercially successful, you will be able to afford acquiring more newer test devices, but the old one may be the most valuable one for app testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using my old iPhone 3G for developement, mostly because it allows me to see how my code runs on one of the slowest devices out there.

The phone is not currently signed up with AT&T and it still works fine for development. For data access the wifi works fine without a carrier account. It also has the camera and (basic) GPS/mapping.

I could probably pick up a used iPhone 3G off one of the auction site relatively cheaply.